# ActiveAdmin Comment model not working properly

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activeadmin

I created a blog by following the [Getting Started with Rails](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/getting_started.html) precisely. And then I following the tutorial here to try ActiveAdmin: http://activeadmin.info/documentation.html.

It's working fine for the Post and Tag models (I logged in and created/add/edited stuff) but not the Comment model.

```
rails generate active_admin:resource Comment

create  app/admin/comments.rb
```

Then when I try to start the server I get this:

```
rails server=> Booting WEBrick
=> Rails 3.0.7 application starting in development on http://0.0.0.0:3000
=> Call with -d to detach
=> Ctrl-C to shutdown server Exiting /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activeadmin-0.2.2/lib/active_admin/namespace.rb:116:in
`find_or_build_resource': Tried to
register Comment as Comment but
already registered to Comment
(ActiveAdmin::ResourceMismatchError)
    from
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activeadmin-0.2.2/lib/active_admin/namespace.rb:45:in
`register'  from
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activeadmin-0.2.2/lib/active_admin.rb:141:in
`register'  from
/Users/myusername/Projects/RoR/blog/app/admin/comments.rb:1:in
`<top (required)>'  from
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.0.7/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:235:in
`load'  from
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.0.7/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:235:in
`block in load'     from
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.0.7/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:225:in
`block in load_dependency'  from
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.0.7/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:596:in
`new_constants_in'  from
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.0.7/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:225:in
`load_dependency'   from
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.0.7/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:235:in
`load'  from
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activeadmin-0.2.2/lib/active_admin.rb:185:in
`block in load!'    from
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activeadmin-0.2.2/lib/active_admin.rb:185:in
`each'  from
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activeadmin-0.2.2/lib/active_admin.rb:185:in
`load!'     from
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activeadmin-0.2.2/lib/active_admin.rb:212:in
`routes'    from
/Users/myusername/Projects/RoR/blog/config/routes.rb:2:in
`block in <top (required)>'     from
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.0.7/lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:233:in
`instance_exec'     from
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.0.7/lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:233:in
`draw'  from
/Users/myusername/Projects/RoR/blog/config/routes.rb:1:in
`<top (required)>'  from
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.0.7/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:235:in
`load'  from
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.0.7/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:235:in
`block in load'     from
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.0.7/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:225:in
`block in load_dependency'  from
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.0.7/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:596:in
`new_constants_in'  from
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.0.7/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:225:in
`load_dependency'   from
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.0.7/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:235:in
`load'  from
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.0.7/lib/rails/application.rb:127:in `block in reload_routes!'    from
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.0.7/lib/rails/application.rb:127:in `each'   from
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.0.7/lib/rails/application.rb:127:in `reload_routes!'     from
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activeadmin-0.2.2/lib/active_admin.rb:123:in
`block in setup'    from
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.0.7/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:420:in
`_run_prepare_callbacks'    from
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.0.7/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:40:in
`initialize'    from
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.0.7/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/stack.rb:33:in
`new'   from
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.0.7/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/stack.rb:33:in
`build'     from
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.0.7/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/stack.rb:79:in
`block in build'    from
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.0.7/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/stack.rb:79:in
`each'  from
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.0.7/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/stack.rb:79:in
`inject'    from
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.0.7/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/stack.rb:79:in
`build'     from
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.0.7/lib/rails/application.rb:162:in `app'    from
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.0.7/lib/rails/application/finisher.rb:35:in
`block in <module:Finisher>'    from
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.0.7/lib/rails/initializable.rb:25:in `instance_exec'     from
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.0.7/lib/rails/initializable.rb:25:in `run'   from
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.0.7/lib/rails/initializable.rb:50:in `block in run_initializers'     from
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.0.7/lib/rails/initializable.rb:49:in `each'  from
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.0.7/lib/rails/initializable.rb:49:in `run_initializers'  from
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.0.7/lib/rails/application.rb:134:in `initialize!'    from
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.0.7/lib/rails/application.rb:77:in
`method_missing'    from
/Users/myusername/Projects/RoR/blog/config/environment.rb:5:in
`<top (required)>'  from
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.0.7/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:239:in
`require'   from
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.0.7/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:239:in
`block in require'  from
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.0.7/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:225:in
`block in load_dependency'  from
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.0.7/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:596:in
`new_constants_in'  from
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.0.7/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:225:in
`load_dependency'   from
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.0.7/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:239:in
`require'   from
/Users/myusername/Projects/RoR/blog/config.ru:3:in
`block in <main>'   from
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.2.1/lib/rack/builder.rb:46:in
`instance_eval'     from
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.2.1/lib/rack/builder.rb:46:in
`initialize'    from
/Users/myusername/Projects/RoR/blog/config.ru:1:in
`new'   from
/Users/myusername/Projects/RoR/blog/config.ru:1:in
`<main>'    from
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.2.1/lib/rack/builder.rb:35:in
`eval'  from
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.2.1/lib/rack/builder.rb:35:in
`parse_file'    from
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.2.1/lib/rack/server.rb:162:in
`app'   from
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.2.1/lib/rack/server.rb:248:in
`wrapped_app'   from
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.2.1/lib/rack/server.rb:213:in
`start'     from
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.0.7/lib/rails/commands/server.rb:65:in `start'   from
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.0.7/lib/rails/commands.rb:30:in
`block in <top (required)>'     from
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.0.7/lib/rails/commands.rb:27:in
`tap'   from
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.0.7/lib/rails/commands.rb:27:in
`<top (required)>'  from
script/rails:6:in `require'     from
script/rails:6:in `<main>'
```

Your help would be appreciated.

Comment: This is not longer an issue in the current release of ActiveAdmin.

Answer (score 47, accepted):

Look like a bug (ActiveAdmin has it's own built-in `Comment` model/class already): https://github.com/gregbell/active_admin/issues/64

A possible workaround could be to give your `Comment` model a different name within in `app/admin/comments.rb`:

```
ActiveAdmin.register Comment, :as => "PostComment" do
```

Answer (score 5):

try this

run in terminal

```
rails g active_admin:resource ActiveAdmin::Comment
```

---

add a following lines  in
**app/admin/active_admin_comment.rb**

```
ActiveAdmin.register ActiveAdmin::Comment, :as => "Comment" do
end
```

---

after that edit **config/initializers/active_admin**

```
[...]
  config.comments_registration_name = "OldComment"
  config.show_comments_in_menu = false
[...]
```

And now you have opportunity to customize a **comments** in **app/admin/active_admin_comment.rb**
but i still didn't find solution to add **:update** and **:destroy** actions

Comment: In 1.0.pre it is now part of the config, just uncomment the lines in the `active_admin.rb` config. No need to reopen the definition of comments, commenting can be disabled.

Answer (score 3):

Dylan's answer is a great start. In addition to his, I needed to overwrite the controller resource/collection methods.

`app/admin/comments.rb`

```
ActiveAdmin.register Comment, as: 'QuestionComment' do
   controller do
     defaults resource_class: Comment, collection_name: 'comments', instance_name: 'comment'
   end
end
```

Basically, you're just overwriting the defaults of inherited resource controller (https://github.com/josevalim/inherited_resources#overwriting-defaults)

(yes, this is still an issue in 2014 even in the 1.0.0 prerelease version, but it appears that they want to fix it from reading the github issues)

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem with version 1.0.0.pre, but thankfully, you can suppress ActiveAdmin comments altogether with a config in active_admin.rb then you don't have to alias your own Comment model anymore as mentioned above.

config/initializers/active_admin.rb

```
  ...
  # == Admin Comments
  #
  # This allows your users to comment on any resource registered with Active Admin.
  #
  # You can completely disable comments:
  config.allow_comments = false
  #
```

It's also listed in the docs: https://github.com/gregbell/active_admin/blob/master/docs/1-general-configuration.md#comments